# Zoom in and out of -- div overflow

Tags: javascript, html, zooming

i just wanna know how i can zoom in and out in the div zoom with an Javascript Code.

So i have an DIV. In the DIV is another DIV which ist much larger than the div which is superordinated. Just like an MAP.
I wanna Scroll in and out in this div however i want.

I don't need the full code i just wanna know where i have to search for.

HERE are the IMAGES what i wanna do:[ZOOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYxTN.jpg) [ZOOMIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PILkV.jpg) [ZOOMOUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o38d0.jpg)

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Please could you rephrase it.

Comment: @LucaNeri Better?

Answer (score 2):

You can emulate a "zoom" into a div with **CSS transform: scale()** property. Here's some JS code that toggles between a zoomed in/out state on click.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Testing</title>
    <style>
      #zoom {
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 100px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="zoom"><p>Test</p></div>
    </div>
    <script>
      // On click, scale up or down
      document.getElementById("zoom").addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.style.transform === "scale(2)"
          ? (this.style.transform = "scale(1)")
          : (this.style.transform = "scale(2)");
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

You can add transition CSS for smooth zoom in/out.

```
    transition: transform 2s;
  -webkit-transition: transform 2s;
```